# Xamarin app deadlocks when making api call

Tags: c#, xamarin, dotnet-httpclient

My Xamarin app deadlocks when trying to make API call (asp.net core web API). The mobile app is using Android emulator. I created both API and client app following Microsoft's own tutorial. Requests run normally when making call with Postman or directly in the browser of my dev machine.

Constants class:

```
public static class Constants
{
        public static string BaseAddress =
        DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android
          ? "https://10.0.2.2:44348"
          :"https://localhost:44348";

        public static string AppointmentsUrl = $"{BaseAddress}/api/appointments/";
}
```

Handler:

```
public class AppointmentHandler
{
    HttpClient client;
    JsonSerializerOptions serializerOptions;

    private List<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }

    public AppointmentHandler()
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
        serializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
            WriteIndented = true
        };
    }


    public async Task<List<Appointment>> GetAppointments()
    {
        Appointments = new List<Appointment>();
        try
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format(Constants.AppointmentsUrl, string.Empty));

            // the program deadlocks here
            HttpResponseMessage response = await this.client.GetAsync(uri);
            
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Appointment>>(content, serializerOptions);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var m = e.Message;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you verified connectivity from your emulator to your service url using the browser IN the emulator?

Comment: Yes I've tried. It says "bad request, invalid hostname". But why it doesn't retrieve the status code to the application?

Comment: a status code requires a successful connection to the server, you are not getting that far

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using

```
.ConfigureAwait(false)
```

This is a common issue with async code and user interfaces. More here:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/174173/should-i-use-configureawait-bool-or-not